# How to include jar file when compiling java files using a batch file

Tags: java, jar, javac, red5

I use this now without any jars and it works fine and compiles all the java files.

`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javac" org/redfire/screen/*.java  -deprecation -classpath .
pause`

I want to know how to include jar files to this because some files need the `servlet-api.jar`. I tried

`" -cp servlet-api.jar C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javac" org/redfire/screen/*.java  -deprecation -classpath . 
pause`, but I get

`The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.` in cmd.

Comment: Why would you put the `-cp` command line argument *before* the command itself?

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought that's how should be done because for compiling in cmd we type javac -cp jarname.jar javafile.java

Comment: Yes, so why would you put javac *after* the -cp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javac" -deprecation -cp .;servlet-api.jar -d .  org\redfire\screen\*.java`

**Note**: Assusing you have `servlet-api.jar` in current directory and all java files in `org\redfire\screen` directory from current location from where you are executing this command/batch-file

A better way to write in batch file is:

```
set JAVA_COMPILER="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javac"
set CLASSPATH=.;servlet-api.jar

%JAVA_COMPILER%  -deprecation -cp %CLASSPATH% -d . org\redfire\screen\*.java 
pause
```

Comment: what's the dot for in `set CLASSPATH`

Comment: `.` includes  the current working directory into the classpath